# Google maps sometimes does not return a geocoded value for string

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I have the following code:
It basically looks into a HTML list and geocodes and marks each item. it does it correctly 8 out of ten but sometimes I get an error I set for show in the console.

I can't think of anything. Any thoughts is much appreciated.

```
$(function () {

var map = null;
var geocoder = null;

function initialize() {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        // Specifies that the element with the ID map is the container for the map
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        // Sets an initial map positon (which mainly gets ignored after reading the adderesses list)
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
        // Instatiates the google Geocoder class
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        // Sets map zooming controls on the map
        map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
        // Allows the mouse wheel to control the map while on it
    }
}


function showAddress(address, linkHTML) {
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.getLatLng(address,

    function (point) {
        if (!point) {
            console.log('Geocoder did not return a location for ' + address);
        }
        else {
            map.setCenter(point, 8);
            var marker = new GMarker(point);
            map.addOverlay(marker);
            // Assigns the click event to each marker to open its balloon
            GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                marker.openInfoWindowHtml(linkHTML);
            });

        }
    }
);
    }
} // end of show address function

initialize();

// This iterates through the text of each address and tells the map
// to show its location on the map. An internal error is thrown if
// the location is not found.
$.each($('.addresses li a'), function () {
    var addressAnchor = $(this);
    showAddress(addressAnchor.text(), $(this).parent().html());
});
});
```

which looks into this HTML:

```
<ul class="addresses">
                <li><a href="#">Central London</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">London WC1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">London Shoreditch</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">London EC1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">London EC2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">London EC3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">London EC4</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: sorry about all the basic comments. its for a client who needs to know what each line does

Comment: Are you saying that it fails intermittently for the same address, or that it just fails 2/10 in general?

Comment: It fails completely random. sometimes for an address is has found before and sometimes for all. Then I refresh and it works fine again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe its the geocoders query limit, because you're asking the api to frequently?
Its just a guess. I ran into this problem more than once.

Comment: Thank for the answer virtualize. It well could be what you are suggesting. Although I am testing the app from a US sanctioned country but if it was anything to do with that probably the service would not work at all rather than sometimes failing. I guess this is the scenario where I have to suggest to my client to get a google maps commercial license.